# How can I write the correct XPath from Html code below?

Tags: xpath

I have the following HTML code:

```
<a onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNGCu8Es2fdCh_-QSfscnnAaMVAngg','','0CB0QFjAA','','',event)"
href="http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;q=&amp;esrc=s&amp;source=web&amp;cd=1&amp;cad=rja&amp;uact=8&amp;ved=0CB0QFjAA&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FBrazil&amp;ei=XaviVIqPA8KqNq3-gpgO&amp;usg=AFQjCNGCu8Es2fdCh_-QSfscnnAaMVAngg&amp;bvm=bv.85970519,d.eXY">
Brazil - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</a>
```

Here is the Xpath from the HTML code above using Firefox Firebug :

```
/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/div[6]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/ol/li[1]/div/h3/a
```

How can I write the Xpath code?

Comment: Something appears to be missing...

Comment: Here is the steps to generate the HTML code :

Comment: Google.ca and then type "brazil". On the first link, you will see Brazil wikipedia link, I would like to use selenium to get this link.  I must find the correct Xpath to be able to grab the web element.

Comment: What am I missing Ivan ?

Comment: The HTML code wasn't visible in the quesion. I fixed that.

Comment: So, you already have an XPath. What do you need to "write" then?

Comment: Yes correct!  I need to write the Xpath.

Comment: What do you mean? You already have it. `"/html/body/div[1]...etc"` is an XPath.

Comment: Okay so, IWebElement brazilWiki = driver.FindElements(By.Xpath(/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/div[6]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/ol/li[1]/div/h3/a[@href='http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&']));   Is this correct?

Comment: Well, it will work on the same page you copied it from but will likely not work on any other page. So specify which set of pages you want to find this element on and how to distinguish it from others - on other pages it will likely not look exactly the same, either.

Comment: True,  I need to find another way which this Xpath can be more flexible to run in several browsers.   I am new on Selenium and Xpath.   I have noticed the web elements can be different to one browser to another.   Thank you Ivan.

Comment: So, what do you need to find and where, in human terms? The link to the Brazil enwiki page in `google.ca` results?

Answer (score 1):

For a "search-friendly" XPath, you have to only use entities that do not change between pages and, preferably, do not rely too much on the page's internal details that can change without notice. Here, these are:

- The title of the search result
- The fact it's a hyperlink

  ```
  //a[text()='Brazil - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia']
  ```

This worked for me for the page retrieved with Firefox 28 but not with Python `requests` - in the latter case, the word "Brazil" in the hyperlink text was bolderized and this had to be applied instead:

```
   //a[text()=' - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia']/*[text()='Brazil']/..
```

Comment: I tried this :  IWebElement brazilWiki = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a [text()='Brazil - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia']"));   It did not work.                       Error:  An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll
Additional information: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=39.0.2171.99)

Comment: The HTML turns out to be different for different browsers, see the update.